# Does Android cache drawable resources loaded in xml layout files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `ViewPager` which loads lots of fragments (+20). Each one of these fragments is just an instance of one single fragment, and the only thing that changes is the content of each one. The UI for this fragment has, among other widgets, 4 different `ImageViews` which all load the same resource drawable but are of course located in different parts of the UI.

Now, if we take into account that I might have for example 20 fragments with this scheme, we're talking about 80 (20*4) ImageViews which would all load the same drawable.

So, that made me wonder, does Android cache in any way resources that are loaded from xml layouts? If not, is there a better option then simply loading this drawable in code, caching it and attaching it programmatically to their corresponding ImageView every time a new instance of this fragment gets created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android does have some kind of recycling management with `Drawable` component. I have noticed this very clear when using same resources for `Drawables`  and using `ColorFilter` with them, and I have ended seeing wrong color with previously created drawable which hasn't been visible yet in UI.

I would say your approach is OK.

In this post Romain explains that `Drawables` share some information, for example the `Bitmap` they are drawing: http://www.curious-creature.org/category/android/page/2/

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look at it. I guess I could also test both strategies and keep an eye on the heap to see if there's any difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just a summary of the blog entry provided in the accepted answer, so people don't have to read the whole blog. In the example in the blog post, the author talks about creating various Buttons, which will eventually all share the same drawable:

> This way, all buttons across all applications share the same bitmap,
>   which saves a lot of memory.

So yes, apparently Android does optimize resources loaded.

Answer (score -4):

here is how you change the image of the imageview programaticaly :

```
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable);
    your_imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

hope this help ,you can find more tutoriel here[click here](http://tutorielandroid.blogspot.com/)