# How many times android, read to string.xml when a string is obtained?

Tags: android, string.xml

If I have this variable activity.getString(R.string.urlService);
in my strings.xml in android, and I use this variable 3 times in my code. How many times android read string.xml file? 
When the android application start the content is upload to memory and is set in the context, and is read once?

Comment: I have never seen it suggested to read values from `strings.xml` and cache them in your Android app, so presumably this file is read once at startup and then cached somewhere.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767818/does-android-cache-drawable-resources-loaded-in-xml-layout-files) for a discussion around how Android does cache `res/drawables` ... presumably the same is happening for `res/values`, where` strings.xml` resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activity.getString(R.string.urlService);
```

This will **get** the string 3 times. When i say get the string, i mean a reference to the string that is defined in strings.xml. There is no efficiency benefits here. Infact doing

```
String myString = activity.getString(R.string.urlService);
```

and using `myString` is more efficient than calling `activity.getString` 3 times. But this is **very very negligible**! And the benefits of using `strings.xml` far outweigh the cons.

Then why use **strings.xml**?

The beauty of strings.xml is that it makes your life extremely easy when it comes to `Localization`. Let's say you want your app translated to 10 other languages. All you need to do, is give your strings.xml file to the translator (which google provides by the way for a price), and the translator will give you 10 strings.xml in 10 different languages. You place the english strings.xml in `values-en/`, the Spanish ones in `values-es/` and so on.